# Not being able to include CSS file in JSP

Tags: html, css, spring, jsp

[image: Here is the directory structure of my project .]

I have the css file in the resources folder in webapp .
I have tried mapping the resource in spring-servlet through this

```
<mvc:resources mapping="/resources/**" location="/webapp/resources"  
cache-period="31556926"/>
```

but it didn't work. How do i get to include this CSS in the JSP page

linking the css with this

```
    <link href="<c:url value="/resources/css/main.css" />" rel="stylesheet">
```

Comment: Which url does you "invoke" to get the resources, and/or how is the css file referenced in you jsp (please post the code)?

Comment: <link href="<c:url value="/resources/brands.css" />" rel="stylesheet">

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The files from `src/main/webapp` gets located in your `war` in its root directory, therfore you must not have `/webapp` in you resource location:

```
<mvc:resources mapping="/resources/**" location="resources/"  cache-period="31556926"/>
```

*BTW: add a slash at the END of your location!*